# My code is not running on GPU after I restarted my system

Tags: pytorch, yolov8

So I recently installed CUDA on my system, every thing worked fine untill I restarted my pc. I am basically training a YOLOv8 model on custom dataset. When I installed CUDA the program was using the GPU with no problem. But after restart it is not using the GPU and throwing error

`RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect. For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. Compile with` TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA `to enable device-side assertions.`

I have already checked, all the drivers a perfectly fine and before restarting I had already run this code 4-5 times and it gave me good results too.
Here's the code I'm trying to run.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import multiprocessing

def my_function():
    model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")
    results = model.train(data="config.yaml", epochs=700)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()  # Only necessary on Windows
    # Spawn a new process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```